# Triple Monitors, Dual Cards, and Openbox problem

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, openbox

I have a 3 monitor setup on 2 video cards (nvidia and onboard intel) and they all work, however not quite the way I'd like. When it was just the 2 monitors on the nvidia, Openbox would treat them as a single desktop/worksapce but still as separate monitors and allow me to full screen an app on just that one monitor. Now that i have the other card and monitor active (on its own xserver), the 2 nvidia monitors act as a single screen and apps full screen across both. GDM treats each monitor individually (login prompt centers on Screen0, Screen1 has wallpaper, Screen2 is just plain X) but once i get into openbox the nvidia's merge, centering everything between them and the intel behaves as normal. Does anyone have any idea how to retain the dual monitor behaviour for the nvidia screens?

my xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0   "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1   "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S24D390"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
#   HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
#   VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VX238"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

#    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
#    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 750 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    VendorName     "Intel Corporation"
    Option         "AccelMethod" "uxa"
#    Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"
#    Option      "TearFree"    "true"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "SLI" "off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "SLI" "off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_60_0 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/598

In the attachments you find a working xorg.conf.d :
"zaphod mode" = four separate independant screens,
working with e.g. twm, fluxbox, xfce.

Unfortunately, latest Openbox x11-wm/openbox-3.6.1 (Gentoo) for me 
also only opened a working Desktop environment on Screen 0.0 only -
0.1 .. 0.3 remained blank,
although "xrandr -q --screen 0.n" delivered correct results.